# Python argument parser that doesn't assume all arguments are strings

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Is there a Python module that can parse a sequence of what seems to be command-line options and arguments where option values are not strings? That is, I may have a sequence like this:

```
("--foo", foo, "--bar", bar1, bar2, baz)
```

Here `"--foo"` and `"--bar"` are strings and others are arbitrary objects. I want to be able to define that e.g. `"--foo"` takes one argument and `"--bar"` takes two and have the parser to just read what follows these options without attempting to parse them as well.

I thought I'd use the standard `argparse` with maybe `nargs` or a custom `argparse.Action`, but even with these things in place it expects each argument to be a string and raises an exception if it cannot read what it starts with.

**Update:** Suprisingly the old `optparse` can do this.

Comment: Maybe an example command line invocation would help.

Comment: If you have the answer, feel free to post it.  There should be a button towards the bottom of the screen that says `Answer Your Question`

Comment: This is not a command line, it's more like a function call from another application into an embedded Python interpreter. For many deeply rooted reasons I want to make that function call to resemble a command line with options, positional parameters, and maybe even subcommands.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, the old `optparse` handled this out of the box. That is:

```
>>> class UniqueSnowflake(object): pass
...
>>> parser = optparse.Parser()
>>> parser.add_option("--foo", type="string") # means 'as is'
>>> parser.parse(["--foo", UniqueSnowflake()])
(<Values at 0x... {'foo': <...UniqueSnowflake object at 0x...>}>, [])
```